# Materialize tooltips getting stuck on top of page

Tags: html, css, tooltip, materialize

EDIT: Here is a URL with a video showing the behavior:
`https://streamable.com/xx39s4`

While messing with Materialize elements, I saw an odd behavior in my website: the Materialize Tooltips  (https://materializecss.com/tooltips.html) stick to the top of the screen when you scroll down (randomly, as far as my tests go). I just set an example in my own domain where you can see the behavior:
`https://leogalski.com/test.html`

The issue also happens when using w3schools' TryIt editor:
`https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GFLHMVLGB1NP`

But strangely enough the issue DOES NOT happen using JSFiddle:
`https://jsfiddle.net/8bryjL9w/`

I already tried messing with JSFiddle's options to see if somehow the issue starts happens... no luck
Tried also changing Materialize Tooltips' css options... No luck
Tried changing screen sizes... No luck
Tried looking for other threads with the same issue... Incredibly no luck

Can someone give me an idea on why this might be happening? I'm no web developer, so if I'm saying something stupid, please forgive me :-)

Comment: I can't replicate this in Chrome. Which browser and version are you using?

Comment: Hi Sean! Thanks for the answer. I am precisely using Chrome 83.0.4103.97 (64-bit). I was also able to reproduce the behavior in IE 11 :-(

Comment: I don't use IE bu it is fine for me in 83.0.4103.61. Maybe clear your cache, try incognito mode. The tooltips disappear so quickly for me - are yours staying? Are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: Hi Sean, thanks again! I cleaned the cache and also tested it in incognito mode. I also tested using another laptop - this time running Linux - and the issue was there too. I will try to be more clear on the behavior showing a video: ```https://streamable.com/xx39s4``` Thanks!